# How to repeat request in Angular?

Tags: angular, angular8

I have component with method: `load():`

```js
load() {
   this.simpleDictService
      .get(
         this.dictCode,
         this.pagination.from,
         this.pagination.to,
         this.showDeleted
      )
      .subscribe((response: IResponseDict) => { this.res = response; });
   }
```

This method is called whenever I typed a message into an input field.

As a result, I get a response data from server:

```
this.res = response;
```

There is also an Export to Excel button. Upon clicking on it, I want to repeat the previous request that was sent to server with additional parameters.
How do I do this in Angular?

Actually, I can store previous URL in storage then modify it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try now by the following way

```
    private subscriptionFileUpload;

    load() {
     if (this.subscriptionFileUpload) {
       this.subscriptionFileUpload.unsubscribe();
     }
     this.subscriptionFileUpload = this.simpleDictService
          .get(
            this.dictCode,
            this.pagination.from,
            this.pagination.to,
            this.showDeleted
          )
          .subscribe((response: IResponseDict) => { this.res = response; });
    }
```

Call load method when your need or you can release into `.subscribe`